# Add/remove dynamically koloda views

Tags: ios, swift, swipe

I use Koloda library to manage draggable cards on screen.

My datasource is an Array of UIImage:

```
private var numberOfRecommendedUsers: UInt = 5

let urlPicture = NSURL(string:"http://...")
let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlPicture!)
self.dataSource = {
  var array: Array<UIImage> = []
  for _ in 0..<numberOfRecommendedUsers {
    array.append(UIImage(data: imageData!)!)
  }
  return array
}()
```

When the card is swiped, I add one card to the datasource and reloadData():

```
func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAtIndex index: UInt, inDirection direction: SwipeResultDirection) {
  let urlPicture = NSURL(string:"http:...")
  let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlPicture!)
  self.dataSource.insert(UIImage(data: imageData!)!, atIndex: kolodaView.countOfCards)
  kolodaView.reloadData()
}
```

That works great but it is very memory consuming (users will swipe hundreds of cards).

When a card is swiped, it is not used anymore.
So a solution would be to remove it from the datasource when a new card is added. Thus, the datasource will always consume only 5 elements in memory.

The only way I found to do this is the following:

```
func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAtIndex index: UInt, inDirection direction: SwipeResultDirection) {
  let urlPicture = NSURL(string:"http:...")
  let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlPicture!)
  self.dataSource.insert(UIImage(data: imageData!)!, atIndex: kolodaView.countOfCards)
  self.dataSource.removeAtIndex(0)
  kolodaView.resetCurrentCardIndex()
}
```

The problem is that `resetCurrentCardIndex()` call reloads the cards loading animation at each swipe.

The expected behaviour would be to add a new card at the end of the datasource and remove the first element already swiped without any animation.

Any way to do that? Or maybe there is a better and proper solution I did not see...

Thank for any feedback.

## EDIT

I just found a way to remove animation when reloading cards. There is a delegate method to implement:

```
func kolodaShouldApplyAppearAnimation(koloda: KolodaView) -> Bool {
  return !self.reloadData
}
```

The swipe delegate method becomes:

```
func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAtIndex index: UInt, inDirection direction: SwipeResultDirection) {
  let urlPicture = NSURL(string:"http:...")
  let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlPicture!)
  self.dataSource.insert(UIImage(data: imageData!)!, atIndex: kolodaView.countOfCards)
  self.dataSource.removeAtIndex(0)
  self.reloadData = true
  kolodaView.resetCurrentCardIndex()
  self.reloadData = false
}
```

That is the behaviour I expected, If someone has a better or proper solution, feel free to propose.

## EDIT 2

I implemented the suggestion made by James.

I made a Class for what will be displayed in koloda view:

```
private var numberOfUsers: UInt = 5

class KolodaUser {
  var photoUrlString = ""
  var firstname = ""
  var age = 0
  var id = ""

  init () {
  }

  convenience init(_ dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    self.init()

    firstname = (dictionary["firstname"] as? String)!
    photoUrlString = ((dictionary["pictures"]) as? [String])![0]
    age = (dictionary["age"] as? Int)!
    id = (dictionary["id"] as? String)!
  }
}

@IBOutlet weak var kolodaView: KolodaView!
var koloUsers = Array<KolodaUser>()
```

When the view is loaded, I fetch 5 users data from remote DB:

```
func fetchUsers() {
  getUsers(limit: 5, onCompleted: {(users) in
    for user in users! {
      if let koloUserDic = user as?  Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        self.koloUsers.append(KolodaUser(koloUserDic))
      }
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      self.kolodaView.reloadData()
    }
  })
}
```

Now, my koloda delegate methods are the following:

```
func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAtIndex index: UInt, inDirection direction: SwipeResultDirection) {
  if direction == .Left {
    // get one user from DB
    getUsers(limit: 1, onCompleted: {(users) in
      for user in users! {
        if let koloUserDic = user as?  Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
          self.koloUsers.append(KolodaUser(koloUserDic))
        }
      }
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.kolodaView.reloadData()
      }
    })
  }
}

func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIView {
  let kolodaUserView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("KolodaUserView",
                                                       owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? KolodaUserView
  let user = self.koloUsers[Int(index)]
  kolodaUserView?.photoImageView?.setImageWithUrl(NSURL(string: "http://.../" + user.photoUrlString)!)
  kolodaUserView?.nameAndAgeLabel?.text = "\(user.firstname)" + ", " + "\(user.age)"

  return kolodaUserView!
}
```

The function `setImageWithUrl` is from https://github.com/namanhams/Swift-UIImageView-AFNetworking repository.

About this solution, you can notice that `KolodaUser` objects are infinitely added to koloda view datasource array.
If user swipes thousand times, that will lead to a very big array but I think it will not be a memory problem. Maybe I'm wrong?

Thank you for any feedback on this new solution.

Comment: How are you managing the list URLs for the images you're loading?  You've effectively created an image cache here, but since you're adding a removing objects directly to and from the `dataSource` array, you have really aggressively manage the koloda view.  Why not make `dataSource` an array of all the URLs for images you're going to want, and then use the `UIImageView+AFNetworking` category's `setImageWithURL:` method to update the card?  AFNetworking takes care of image cache management for you.

Comment: @James: I just edited my post with a new solution based on your comment. May I have your feeling about it?